# How to update column through SQL injection?

Tags: sql, code-injection

I haven't found much information on this, but I heard it is possible to enter SQL queries into the URL bar to extract data from a database, I was just wondering if it was also possible to update a column or table through it.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 1 = '2' 
AND 3 = '$input'
```

Is using an update query in the URL bar possible, and if so, how?

Comment: This should not be downvoted. SQL injection by itself is neither illegal not immoral. People just _assume_ that.

Comment: Exactly, i seen many people asking similar questions of it, i just wanted to know if it was possible and how it goes to take my attention about it in my future codes

Comment: For all the people downvoting this: Do you know what SQL injection is? If yes, how come? Maybe you researched it? Why is researching SQL injection less evil than asking a question about it. You are as "evil" as him. (You aren't).

Comment: Then you should ask how to prevent it and not how to exploit it.

Comment: I want to know how the process goes, and would also gladly to know how to prevent it but isn't it legit to get more details of how it works, just general life info :)

Comment: If your intention is learning, the best way to increase your understanding is take the good examples below and experiment with your own database. Then you can see for yourself what works, what doesn't, and what protects against it.

Comment: This is very good question! I also need the answer of this questions AND I won't hack anyone website but my own.

Answer (score 6):

If someone creates a SQL query string like this

```vb
 sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '" & input & "';"
```

then if the input is

```vb
input = "John'; DELETE FROM table WHERE 'x'='x"
```

The resulting SQL will be

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'John'; DELETE FROM table WHERE 'x'='x';
```

It will contain two SQL statements. The second one can then do about anything the injector wants.

---

There are two possibilities to prevent this to happen.

## 1

Escape the single quotes in the input

```vb
 sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '" & Replace(input, "'", "''") & "';"
```

turning the bad input into a part of the string

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'John''; DELETE FROM table WHERE ''x''=''x';
```

## 2

Use parameters instead of string concatenation

```vb
cmd = new Command("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = @n")  
cmd.AddParameter("@n", input)  
result = cmd.Execute()
```

---

The details depend on the database, the database access technology and the programming language used. My examples have to be understood as pseudo code.

Comment: What if the result ended with this
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'John'; DELETE FROM table WHERE 'x'='x';'
it ends with a single quote that belonged to the value

Comment: @user1150271: We're not going to help you hack a website.  There's enough general information here; please figure the rest out on your own.

Comment: @user1150271: I hope that you are not going to hack web sites. Make the world better, not worse.

Comment: @user1150271 It want because in the user input is missing the ending '